# Somar horas trabalhadas Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho registros do trajeto de um caminhão numa tabela.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

===================================================

Esse exemplo aí em cima tenho 5 registros que peguei na tabela verificando Velocidade > 0
Os registros de 1 à 3 percebemos que é sequencial. Aí houve uma pause e o caminhão voltou a andar 2 horas depois.

Se eu somar a hora na consulta SQL vai dar que ele trabalhou 1 dia, 2 horas e alguns segundos. Quando na verdade foi 30 segundos (1 ao 3). 
E teve mais 2 starts dia 30( nº 4) e dia 31 (nº 5).

Como eu consigo a quantidade total de horas ou segundos trabalhado ? 
Observação a tabela tem mais de 500 mil registros.  Queria pegar no período de 1 semana a quantidade de

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor sua pergunta?

Comment: O seu segundo paragrafo é que ferrou a coisa, poderia explicar melhor? como diferenciar um dos outros???

Comment: As entradas de data hora deveriam ter um indicador de partida ou chegada. Outra coisa banco de dados normalmente não ignora a data, então pra calcular toral de horas vai ter que quebrar a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode agrupar por data formatada e depois utilizar a função [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) para obter a diferença da menor data para a maior data em segundos:

```
SELECT caminhao,
       DATE_FORMAT(data, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(data)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(data)) AS segundos
  FROM tabela t
 GROUP BY caminhao, DATE_FORMAT(data, '%d/%m/%Y')
 ORDER BY caminhao, data;
```

Comment: Obrigado + uma vez amigo